# How do I get out of ESC mode in zsh?

Tags: shell, unix, zsh

When using zsh, I sometimes accidentally press Escape out of habit, expecting it to clear the entire line as it does in Windows.  Instead, it goes into a mode that I'm not sure how to get out of.  The cursor goes back one character, and some keys perform some special commands, but all I really want to do is get out of this mode and be able to press Ctrl+U to clear the line.

Searching around has been tough - I get results for escaping characters.

Comment: Questions like this should probably go on superuser instead of SO, btw.

Comment: @calavicci I wasn't aware of that one, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: press `a`.

Medium answer: press `a`, then enter `bindkey -e`.

Long answer: Like a lot of UNIX shells, zsh has an emacs-like mode and a vi-like mode. You're in vi-like mode, and ESC takes you out of the vi-like insert mode. `a` puts you back into insert mode, with the cursor after the current character. (Sorry for the two different uses of "mode," but it is the accepted terminology in both cases.)

`bindkey -e` overrides the settings from the rc files and puts zsh into emacs mode, which only has one mode (i.e., no "ESC mode"), so this won't bother you any more. Unfortunately, it won't carry over to your next shell invocation. `bindkey -v` would switch from emacs mode back to vi mode.

In the absence of any other configuration, zsh defaults to emacs mode, so unless there's something in one of the rc files, the likely culprit is that the EDITOR variable is some form of vi, which causes zsh to default to vi mode. If you don't like vi mode, then you should probably hunt down what part of the system-wide or user-specific configuration is causing zsh to default to vi mode and turn it off by removing it or overriding it in one of those rc files.

Comment: Thank you!  It's pretty funny that it turned out to be vi mode that's been giving me trouble, considering I have been a vim fan for some time.

Comment: Caught me by surprise the first time, too, and I've been a die-hard vimmer for many years. ;)

Comment: I've used `vim` for 20+ years, and still prefer Emacs keybindings in the shell over vi modes.

Answer (score 1):

If everything else fails, when you're in ESC mode, type :w then Enter to save, and then :q to exit. You can also type :wq and Enter

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).